# File.Open throws IOException, but file is never open/shown

Tags: c#, file-io, ioexception

I am doing a simple test in code, as follows:

```
try
{
    File.Open(path);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

`path` is a string declared above. This routine is called when a button is pressed, and the first time it is called, it "works normally" (in quote, because although it doesn't throw an exception, the file is never open/shown). The second time it is pressed, the following exception is thrown:

> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

However, the file is actually never open. I monitor it with Task Manager, and no instance of the file is ever exhibited.

I tried using `using (File.Open(path)) {}`, but to no success.

Can anybody help me? It seems like a basic mistake I'm doing, but I can't find it.

**UPDATE**

Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen provided the correct answer, pointing out that my mistake was actually about the concept, not the code. Thanks!

Comment: `File.Open` will return a stream, which keeps the file open. If you're not able to see this with whatever tool you used to look for processes that keep the file open, you're using the wrong tool or using the tool incorrectly.

Comment: Now, as to how to fix it, we can't know, because you haven't told us what you wanted to accomplish. Since you're not actually using this stream for anything, my advice would be to simply delete the code, then you get no exception. If that is not a viable solution, please take a step back and tell us what the original problem was that led you to bark up this tree.

Comment: The correct way to open the file and process it would be that using statement, but you will probably need to store a reference to it into a variable. Since you're not doing that either **it is unclear why you are opening the file at all**.

Comment: Re-reading your question here, I have a question for you. Are you trying to start another program? Is `path` here referring to another executable? Because if you're trying to do that, `File.Open` is the wrong method, this will open the file for *reading by your process*. If instead you wanted to open another program, like notepad, you should use `Process.Start` instead. This will also work if the path refers to a document file for which there is a program registered, like opening a .doc file would start Word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood what `File.Open` does.

This method will open the file for reading *by your program*. In other words, that method will return a `Stream` object which you can use to read from and write to that file.

At the end of that operation, you have to close it, which is what `using` would do for you.

However, I'm guessing that this is not what you want to do. You keep mentioning that the file does not open, and that you're using the Task Manager to look for the file, not seeing it.

You want `Process.Start` instead. You're trying to open either another executable, such as `notepad.exe`, or you're trying to open a document, like `readme.txt`, that's why you're not using the result of calling that method, and why you're using the Task Manager to look for it.

So, assuming you still want to catch exceptions, this is what you should do:

```
try
{
    Process.Start(path);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind that catch (Exception) is almost always the wrong thing to do. If you want to catch exceptions in an attempt to log them, then it might be fine, but then not re-throwing it isn't particularly fine.

Comment: Nope, you guessed it perfect. I *did* misunderstood what `File.Open()` does. Thanks for clarifying, and pointing out what I should do. As to the Exception comment, this was solely to see what was happening. Thanks once again!

Comment: Good, happy to help. If I were to give you one parting tip for the future, regarding posting on Stack Overflow, is that you might try to explain more about what you expect the code to do next time. You don't even have to be technical about it, just explain what you, as a user of the program, expected to happen when you clicked that button. But very happy I was able to help you :)

Comment: Yes, I’ll keep that in mind. I’m sure that if I had written that the expected behavior was for the file to open and show onscreen, it’d be more assertive. Thanks! ^^